# Preventive Measure for detecting Session Fixation attacks

Tags: session-management, session-fixation

From my understanding if i am not wrong in session fixation attacks. The attacker login into the server as a legitimate user and creates a valid session. He then the tricks the compromised user to use his session which has already been fixed. My Question is how to detect session fixation attacks one possible solution I have in my mind

- Bind session identifier with source IP as this is possible with WAF like Modsecurity

The Problem with this approach it may have high false positive as client may be using a proxy server or client may be assigned a dynamic IP address that may change during session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how a session fixation attack works. The attacker must first trick the user into visiting the website using a predetermined session. For example, I could trick you into clicking a shortened link `http://example.com/index.php?PHPSSIDE=BLAHBLAHBLAH`. If you login to `example.com` now, your session will be identified by `BLAHBLAHBLAH`. I'd then simply use the same identifier and login to your session. Other methods include an untrusted sub-domain assigning a session cookie for another sub-domain.

If you trust your sub-domains, just configuring your web server not to use session identifiers (eg. `PHPSSID`) in GET or POST is enough. Pairing the session to an IP address, refreshing the identifier, and session expiry, are all also good extra layers of protection against session *hijacking*.

When implementing a security feature, always think about the majority of your users. Those 90+% whose IP won't change a gazillion time throughout the session, those who won't have their sessions constantly hijacked. For the other 10%, it's alright to show them a re authentication form (entering the password again) when something specious happens.

Comment: I meant same thing i.e. http://example.com/index.php?PHPSSIDE=BLAHBLAHBLAH is not originated by the client correct me if I am wrong.